# Python string iterations

Tags: python, string, loops

What are the logics possible to loop a string into a grid?

For example if I wanted 'water' to print

```
water
aterw
terwa
erwat
rwate
```

I was trying something along the lines of,

```
word = 'water'
for number, letter in enumerate(word):
    if number < len(word):
        print a + word[1:] + word[:1]
```

I do not comprehend how i can achieve this as you can see from my attempt.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [2]: word = 'water'
   ...: for i in range(len(word)):
   ...:     print(word[i:] + word[:i])
water
aterw
terwa
erwat
rwate
```

The `i` loops over all possible indexes, takes the suffix starting at that index and prepends it to the string, obtaining all possible rotations.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
word = 'water'
for i in xrange(len(word)):
   print word[i:] + word[:i]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [collections.deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque), it has a [`rotate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method that will do your job.

> Rotate the deque `n` steps to the right. If `n` is negative, rotate to the
>   left. Rotating one step to the right is equivalent to:
>   `d.appendleft(d.pop())`

**Demo:**

```
from collections import deque
d = deque('water')
for _ in xrange(len(d)):
    print ''.join(d)
    d.rotate(-1)
```

**output:**

```
water
aterw
terwa
erwat
rwate
```

Comment: did not know you could do this! +1 for the discovery of `deque` :-)

Comment: This is kinda heavyweight for an OP that's trying to get slicing down. +/- 0 as I'm not sure if the answer should target the level of the question.

Comment: +1 for efficiency! To match the OP expected output you should swap `rotate` and `print` lines and use `-1` as "step". -0 for the complexity of the answer(the OP seem to be completely new to python and programming...)

Comment: @Bakuriu Fixed the output.